# Is this recursive function correct?

Tags: php, recursion

I have develop this function which uses recursion to call itself. I need to generate a unique activation code.

It goes like this:
1. A random string is generated using the function in seperate class file. (See 2nd Code)
2. I am checking for uniqueness of that string in the activation table so that there are no duplicates.
3. In case if the random string is re-generated though I know that the chances are very less, but I dont want to take any chances. So I am checking it against the table records.

If the generated activated code is already there, then function should call itself again to generate a new activate code and the whole process goes on till we get a unique activation code which doesnt exist in the table records.

My question is that, Have I coded it correctly i.e. the recursion part. Please let me know if its not correct or if anybody has better or effective way to achieve this.

Note: I am calling these functions from a class file. Simply speaking I am using OOPs.
So I need to know the code to call the recursion should be

```
return generateUniqueActivationCode();
```

or

```
return $this->generateUniqueActivationCode();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    // Generate Unique Activation Code
    //*********************************************************************************
    public function generateUniqueActivationCode()
    {
        $mysql = new Mysql();
        $string = new String();

        // This is coming from the 2nd part of code snippet that I have added
        $activation_code = $string->generateActivationCode();

        // Is Activation Code Unique Check
        $sql = "SELECT activation_id FROM ". TABLE_ACTIVATION_CODES ." WHERE activation_code='$activation_code' LIMIT 1";
        $query = $mysql->query($sql);

        if($mysql->rowCount($query) > 0)
        {
            // This function is calling itself recursively
            return generateUniqueActivationCode();
        }
        else
        {
            return $activation_code;
        }
    }
```

This is the code for generating Random Activation code

```
class String
{
    // Generates A Random String (Can be used for generating password etc.)
    //*********************************************************************************
    public function generateRandomString($noofchars=8)
    {
        $salt = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i <= $noofchars)
        {
            $num = rand() % 33;
            $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
            $string = $string . $tmp;
            $i++;
        }
        return $string;
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to prepend `$this` always in PHP (unlike C++).

Comment: so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928491/what-is-correct-syntax-for-calling-a-function-recursively-in-php/13928613#13928613 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have typed it like this:

```
public function generateUniqueActivationCode(){
        $mysql = new Mysql();
        $string = new String();
        do{
            $activation_code = $string->generateActivationCode();
            $sql = "SELECT activation_id FROM ". TABLE_ACTIVATION_CODES ." WHERE activation_code='$activation_code' LIMIT 1";
            $query = $mysql->query($sql);
        }while($mysql->rowCount($query) > 0);
        return $activation_code;
    }
```

Do (that runs ATLEAST one time), but repeats as long as your rowCount returns something bigger than 0.

Comment: Can you explain me how is your coding looking for uniqueness? I mean if the activation code is already there in the table, then how will the function call itself recursively and generate a new activation code?

Comment: If it's already there. it's not unique, right?

and the function is called generateUniqueActivationCode and you'll return one.

Comment: I need the function to return a unique activation code which is not at all used or assigned to any of the records. It seems to me that your function is doing the reverse of it i.e. If there are more than 0 records in the table, then return the activation code.

Comment: I'll type the do psuedo-style for you:

do ONE or as long as WHILE is true.
get new activation code
search for it in database
if matches is bigger than zero, repeat


http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: Thnks buddy, it worked. Sorry about earlier questions, I didnt understood the logic but after going through the do while loop manual I got it all. Thanks again. Cheers !!!!

Comment: @phant0m he said "My question is that, Have I coded it correctly i.e. the recursion part. Please let me know if its not correct or if anybody has better or effective way to achieve this.", so no :)

Comment: He could have been asking for a better way with recursion as implied by `I have develop this function which uses recursion` ;)