# What is correct syntax for calling a function recursively in php

Tags: php, function

I have a function which is using recursion to call itself and I need to know the correct syntax for calling itself.

Note: I am using Object oriented programming technique and the function is coming from a class file.

Below is my function

```
// Generate Unique Activation Code
//*********************************************************************************
    public function generateUniqueActivationCode()
    {
        $mysql = new Mysql();
        $string = new String();

        $activation_code = $string->generateActivationCode();

        // Is Activation Code Unique Check
        $sql = "SELECT activation_id FROM ". TABLE_ACTIVATION_CODES ." WHERE activation_code='$activation_code' LIMIT 1";
        $query = $mysql->query($sql);

        if($mysql->rowCount($query) > 0)
        {
            // This function is calling itself recursively
            return generateUniqueActivationCode(); // <- Is this syntax correct in Oops
        }
        else
        {
            return $activation_code;
        }
    }
```

Should the code to call it recursively be

```
return generateUniqueActivationCode();
```

OR

```
return $this->generateUniqueActivationCode();
```

or if something else other than these 2 ways.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion is the **COMPLETELY WRONG WAY TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM**

Unlike iteration you're filling up the stack, and generating new objects needlessly.

The right way to solve the problem is to generate a random value within a scope which makes duplicates very unlikely, however without some external quantifier (such as a username) to define the scope then iteration is the way to go.

There are further issues with your code - really you should be adding records in the same place where you check for records.

> I am using Object oriented programming technique and the function is coming from a class file

Then it's not a function, it's a method.

And your code is susceptibale to SQL injection.

A better solution would be:

```
class xxxx {
....
public function generateUniqueActivationCode($id)
{
   if (!$this->mysql) $this->mysql = new Mysql();
   if (!$this->string) $this->string = new String();
   $limit=10;

   do {
      $activation_code = $string->generateActivationCode();
      $ins=mysql_escape_string($activation_code);
      $sql="INSERT INTO ". TABLE_ACTIVATION_CODES ." (activation_id, activation_code)"
          . "VALUES ($id, '$ins)";
      $query = $mysql->query($sql);
      if (stristr($query->error(), 'duplicate')) {
         continue;
      }
      return $query->error() ? false : $activation_code;
   } while (limit--);
   return false;
}

} // end class
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call it with the $this variable since your function is part of the instance. So:

```
return $this->generateUniqueActivationCode();
```

PS: Why not just try both methods and see if it generates any errors?